# Using multiple TF-IDF to create a feature

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, text-mining, feature-extraction

I have around 200k comments and I extracted the top 200 words (without stop words) out of their content. Each comment is linked to a **specific date**.
I would like to ask a very stupid question:

Is it okay to take all comments from a **specific date** and compute the empirical mean tf-idf (already known for each of them) for this date? I would just do:

$$ {\displaystyle {\overline {X}}_{n}={\frac {1}{n}}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}} $$

If there are any benefits/odds of doing this, what are they?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What would you like to accomplish?

Comment: @YuseqYaseq im trying to analyse social media content on a daily basis to predict the Bitcoin’s delta at the end of the day. I’m using text content as a feature

Comment: If you're taking the mean TFIDF value across the tokens for one comment, no, this doesn't make any sense. Also if you take the top 200 words among 200k comments you're probably considering most of the comments as empty.